# How to make react navigation header dynamic?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

In my react native app, I am trying to implement a message box in the header which when clicked shows a screen with the users messages. I am trying to make the message icon shown in the header vary depending on whether the user has unread messages or not.

In my AppNavigator file, I have tried using a function which stores whether or not there are unread messages and then returns what should be displayed in the header accordingly.

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation, goBack }) => ({
  title: "Title",
  headerRight: () => {
    // unread_messages = check if user has any unread messages
    }).then((unread_messages) => (
      <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("Messages");
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            { unread_messages ? (
                <Ionicons name="md-mail-unread" size={20}/>
            ) : ( 
                <Ionicons name="md-mail" size={20}/>
            )
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>          
    ))
  }
})
```

Doing this results, in nothing except the title being rendered in the header. Is it possible to query data in navigationOptions and then render depending on that? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use ```Context API``` or ```Redux```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, My suggestion is you should use `redux` store to store the read or unread status of your user's message.

Data query should be put on your screen, then update store's state, the icon will change.